Quantlib: SOFR IRS Fair Rate not the same as inputs
I am making an OIS curve and a SOFR curve with bloomberg quotes
When I valuate a SOFR swap in the same tenors as the SOFR inputs, the FairRates are not the same as the quotes I used to create the curve.
Can somenone please help me?
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import QuantLib as ql
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

s = datetime.now()
# EvaluationDate
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = ql.Date(29,4,2024)


#%% USD OIS Construction

tenor2ql = {'B': ql.Days, 'D': ql.Days, 'M': ql.Months, 'W': ql.Weeks,
            'Y': ql.Years, 'L': ql.Weeks}

# market calendar
calendar = ql.UnitedStates(6)

# input data
str_tenors = ['1B', '1W', '2W', '3W', '1M', '2M', '3M', '4M', '5M', '6M', '9M',
              '12M', '18M', '2Y', '3Y', '4Y', '5Y', '7Y', '10Y', '12Y', '15Y',
              '20Y', '25Y', '30Y', '40Y']

tenor = [tenor2ql[ten[-1]] for ten in str_tenors]
period = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4,
          5, 6, 9, 12, 18, 2, 3, 4,
          5, 7, 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 30,
          40]
data = [0.0533, 0.053302, 0.053308, 0.05332, 0.053362, 0.053377,
        0.053385, 0.053279, 0.053173, 0.052985, 0.05246, 0.051868,
        0.04978 , 0.048395, 0.046192, 0.04474 , 0.043821, 0.04291,
        0.042347, 0.042266, 0.042207, 0.041692, 0.040661, 0.039605,
        0.037396]

# Deposit rates
deposits = {(period[0], tenor[0]): data[0]}

# Swap rates
n = len(period)
swaps = {}
for i in range(1,n):
    swaps[(period[i], tenor[i])] = data[i]

# Rate Quantlib.Quote objects
## desposits
for n, unit in deposits.keys():
    deposits[(n, unit)] = ql.SimpleQuote(deposits[(n, unit)])
    #Tasa cero para el primer tenor
## swap rates
for n, unit in swaps.keys():
    swaps[(n, unit)] = ql.SimpleQuote(swaps[(n, unit)])
    # SimpleQuote es el formato de rates en quantlib

# Rate helpers deposits
dayCounter = ql.Actual360()
settlementDays = 2
## deposits
depositHelpers = [ql.DepositRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(deposits[(n, unit)]),
                                       ql.Period(int(n), unit),
                                       settlementDays,
                                       calendar,
                                       ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                                       False,
                                       dayCounter)
                  for (n, unit) in deposits.keys()]
## swap rates
OIS_Index = ql.FedFunds()
OISHelpers = [ql.OISRateHelper(settlementDays, ql.Period(int(n), unit),
                               ql.QuoteHandle(swaps[(n,unit)]),
                               OIS_Index,
                                ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(),
                                False, 2, ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                                ql.Annual, calendar)
              for n, unit in swaps.keys()]
## helpers merge
hlprUSDOIS = depositHelpers + OISHelpers

crvUSDOIS = ql.PiecewiseLogLinearDiscount(0, calendar,
                                          hlprUSDOIS, ql.Actual360())

crvUSDOIS.enableExtrapolation()
discount_curve = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
discount_curve.linkTo(crvUSDOIS)

#%% SOFR
######################## SOFR Construction ######################

calendar = ql.UnitedStates(6)
# settlement date
dt_settlement = calendar.advance(
        ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate, ql.Period('2D'))

# input data
str_tenor = ['1B', '%2Y', '%3Y', '%4Y', '%5Y', '%6Y', '%7Y', '%8Y', '%9Y',
             '%10Y', '%12Y', '%15Y', '%20Y', '%25Y', '%30Y']
tenor_sofr = [tenor2ql[ten[-1]] for ten in str_tenor]
period_sofr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 30]
data_nonfut = [0.0531, 0.048523, 0.046355, 0.04497 , 0.044095, 0.04357,
               0.043216, 0.042959, 0.042792, 0.042682, 0.042614, 0.042585,
               0.042118, 0.041112, 0.04007]
data_fut = [0.05345, 0.05265, 0.05095, 0.04915, 0.0473]

# IborIndex
swapIndex = ql.Sofr()

# Deposit rates
deposits = {(period_sofr[0], tenor_sofr[0]): data_nonfut[0]}

# Futures rates
n_fut = len(data_fut)
imm = ql.IMM.nextDate(dt_settlement)
imm = dt_settlement
futures = {}
for i in range(n_fut):
    imm = ql.IMM.nextDate(imm)
    futures[imm] = 100-data_fut[i]*100

# Swap rates
n = len(period_sofr)
swaps = {}
for i in range(1, n):
    swaps[(period_sofr[i], tenor_sofr[i])] = data_nonfut[i]

# Rate Qauntlib.Quote objects
## desposits

for n, unit in deposits.keys():
    deposits[(n, unit)] = ql.SimpleQuote(deposits[(n, unit)])
## futures
for d in futures.keys():
    futures[d] = futures[d]
## swap rates
for n, unit in swaps.keys():
    swaps[(n, unit)] = ql.SimpleQuote(swaps[(n, unit)])

# Rate helpers deposits
dayCounter = ql.Actual360()
settlementDays = 2
## deposits
depositHelpers = [ql.DepositRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(deposits[(n, unit)]),
                                       ql.Period(int(n), unit),
                                       settlementDays,
                                       calendar,
                                       ql.ModifiedFollowing,
                                       False,
                                       dayCounter)
                  for n, unit in deposits.keys()]
## futures
months = 3
futuresHelpers = [ql.FuturesRateHelper(
    ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(futures[d])),
    d, months, calendar,
    ql.ModifiedFollowing, True, dayCounter,
    ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0.0)))
    for d in futures.keys()
]

## swap rates
fixedLegFrequency = ql.Annual
fixedLegAdjustment = ql.ModifiedFollowing
fixedLegDayCounter = ql.Actual360()
## swaphelper
swapHelpers = [ql.SwapRateHelper(
    ql.QuoteHandle(swaps[(n,unit)]),
    ql.Period(int(n), unit),
    calendar,
    fixedLegFrequency,
    fixedLegAdjustment,
    fixedLegDayCounter,
    # swapIndex)
    swapIndex,
    ql.QuoteHandle(),
    ql.Period(2, ql.Days),
    discount_curve
    )
    for n, unit in swaps.keys()
]

## helpers merge
hlprSOFR = depositHelpers + futuresHelpers + swapHelpers

# Bootstrap
# crvSOFR = ql.PiecewiseNaturalLogCubicDiscount(0, calendar, hlprSOFR,
#                                               ql.Actual360())
crvSOFR = ql.PiecewiseCubicZero(0, calendar, hlprSOFR, ql.Actual360())

crvSOFR.enableExtrapolation()

crv_usdswp = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
crv_usdswp.linkTo(crvSOFR)


###### SWAP VALUATION #######

for i in range(len(tenor_sofr)):

    legDC = ql.Actual360()
    start =  ql.Date(1,5,2024)
    maturity = ql.UnitedStates(6).advance(start, ql.Period(period_sofr[i], tenor_sofr[i]))
    cal = ql.UnitedStates(6)
    convention = ql.ModifiedFollowing
    termDateConvention = ql.ModifiedFollowing
    rule = ql.DateGeneration.Backward
    isEndOfMonth = False
    cpn_tenor = ql.Period('1Y')
    ibor = ql.Sofr(crv_usdswp)
    
    fixfltSchdl = ql.Schedule(start, maturity, cpn_tenor, cal, convention,
                            termDateConvention, rule, isEndOfMonth)
    
    swap = ql.VanillaSwap(typ, notional, fixfltSchdl, rate, legDC, fixfltSchdl,
                          ibor, 0, legDC)
    
    
    discount_engine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(discount_curve)
    swap.setPricingEngine(discount_engine)
    print((np.round(swap.fairRate(),6)-data_nonfut[i])*10000)

The Output is the difference in basis points between the SOFR fair rates and the inputs:
0.0
-0.059999999999990616
-0.07000000000000062
-0.010000000000010001
0.010000000000010001
0.020000000000020002
0.030000000000030003
0.020000000000020002
0.030000000000030003
0.050000000000050004
0.049999999999980616
0.059999999999990616
0.07000000000000062
0.07000000000000062
0.07000000000000062

Wrong classes.  For SOFR you need OISRateHelper and OvernightIndexedSwap, not SwapHelper and VanillaSwap.  The latter pay a single fixing, the former pay daily compounded fixings.

Thanks! It works now
